# How to get the time for inserting multiple rows in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I am new in cassandra. I have to inserted 100 rows. But I need to know the time for inserting those rows. I dont know how to do it.

This is the code for inserting 1 row. I have 100 rows like this which I'll write in a loop.

```
 public void loadData() {
    session.execute("INSERT INTO songs (id, title, album, artist, tags) "
    + "VALUES ("
    + "756716f7-2e54-4715-9f00-91dcbea6cf50,"
    + "'La Petite Tonkinoise',"
    + "'Bye Bye Blackbird',"
    + "'Joséphine Baker'," + "{'jazz', '2013'})" + ";");
}
```

I need to know the time for inserting those rows. Please any one help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.out.println(System.nanoTime());  put this in the start of your Resultset and also end of  insertion